# Number combination.

Tags: combinations

Can you provide all possible combination of numbers 1 to 16 by 8 not to be repeated? For example 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 but should not to be repeated.

This will be the same for question like All Possible 6/45 Lottery Number Combinations. It just that what i need is 8/16, and yes i need all the number list.

This 1 to 16 numbers where 16 rumbled numbers i just used 1 to 16 numbers as mappings since in this way it will be easier rather than using the original 16 rumble numbers.

Comment: This is not clear.  You just want the number of ways to choose $8$ unordered elements out of $16$?  That's $\binom {16}8$.

Comment: Thanks! It is most likely the same for question about all Possible 6/45 Lottery Number Combinations. The different is that what i want is 8/16.

Comment: @lulu 's comment tells you there are 12870 combinations on that list. We can't write them all down for you.

Comment: To see how to count the number of ways of selecting a subset of $k$ elements from a set with $n$ elements, read this article on [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are indeed `12870` combinations, as mentioned in the comments. However, we can indeed write them all for you ;).

```
from itertools import combinations
r = list(range(1,17))
all_combinations = [",".join(map(str, comb)) for comb in combinations(r, 8)]

with open('combinations.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write("\n".join(all_combinations))
```

produces

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,11
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,8,11
1,2,3,4,5,6,8,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,8,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,8,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,8,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,11
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,9,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,11
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,10,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,6,11,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,11,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,11,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,6,12,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,12,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,13,14
1,2,3,4,5,6,13,15
1,2,3,4,5,6,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10
1,2,3,4,5,7,8,11
1,2,3,4,5,7,8,12
1,2,3,4,5,7,8,13
1,2,3,4,5,7,8,14
1,2,3,4,5,7,8,15
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,11
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,12
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,13
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,14
1,2,3,4,5,7,9,15
1,2,3,4,5,7,10,11
1,2,3,4,5,7,10,12
1,2,3,4,5,7,10,13
1,2,3,4,5,7,10,14
1,2,3,4,5,7,10,15
1,2,3,4,5,7,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,7,11,13
1,2,3,4,5,7,11,14
1,2,3,4,5,7,11,15
1,2,3,4,5,7,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,7,12,14
1,2,3,4,5,7,12,15
1,2,3,4,5,7,13,14
1,2,3,4,5,7,13,15
1,2,3,4,5,7,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,5,8,9,11
1,2,3,4,5,8,9,12
1,2,3,4,5,8,9,13
1,2,3,4,5,8,9,14
1,2,3,4,5,8,9,15
1,2,3,4,5,8,10,11
1,2,3,4,5,8,10,12
1,2,3,4,5,8,10,13
1,2,3,4,5,8,10,14
1,2,3,4,5,8,10,15
1,2,3,4,5,8,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,8,11,13
1,2,3,4,5,8,11,14
1,2,3,4,5,8,11,15
1,2,3,4,5,8,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,8,12,14
1,2,3,4,5,8,12,15
1,2,3,4,5,8,13,14
1,2,3,4,5,8,13,15
1,2,3,4,5,8,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,12
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,13
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,14
1,2,3,4,5,9,10,15
1,2,3,4,5,9,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,9,11,13
1,2,3,4,5,9,11,14
1,2,3,4,5,9,11,15
1,2,3,4,5,9,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,9,12,14
1,2,3,4,5,9,12,15
1,2,3,4,5,9,13,14
1,2,3,4,5,9,13,15
1,2,3,4,5,9,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,5,10,11,13
1,2,3,4,5,10,11,14
1,2,3,4,5,10,11,15
1,2,3,4,5,10,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,10,12,14
1,2,3,4,5,10,12,15
1,2,3,4,5,10,13,14
1,2,3,4,5,10,13,15
1,2,3,4,5,10,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,5,11,12,14
1,2,3,4,5,11,12,15
1,2,3,4,5,11,13,14
1,2,3,4,5,11,13,15
1,2,3,4,5,11,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,12,13,14
1,2,3,4,5,12,13,15
1,2,3,4,5,12,14,15
1,2,3,4,5,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,10
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,11
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,12
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,13
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,14
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,15
1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10
1,2,3,4,6,7,9,11
1,2,3,4,6,7,9,12
1,2,3,4,6,7,9,13
1,2,3,4,6,7,9,14
1,2,3,4,6,7,9,15
1,2,3,4,6,7,10,11
1,2,3,4,6,7,10,12
1,2,3,4,6,7,10,13
1,2,3,4,6,7,10,14
1,2,3,4,6,7,10,15
1,2,3,4,6,7,11,12
1,2,3,4,6,7,11,13
1,2,3,4,6,7,11,14
1,2,3,4,6,7,11,15
1,2,3,4,6,7,12,13
1,2,3,4,6,7,12,14
1,2,3,4,6,7,12,15
1,2,3,4,6,7,13,14
1,2,3,4,6,7,13,15
1,2,3,4,6,7,14,15
1,2,3,4,6,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,6,8,9,11
1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12
1,2,3,4,6,8,9,13
1,2,3,4,6,8,9,14
1,2,3,4,6,8,9,15
1,2,3,4,6,8,10,11
1,2,3,4,6,8,10,12
1,2,3,4,6,8,10,13
1,2,3,4,6,8,10,14
1,2,3,4,6,8,10,15
1,2,3,4,6,8,11,12
1,2,3,4,6,8,11,13
1,2,3,4,6,8,11,14
1,2,3,4,6,8,11,15
1,2,3,4,6,8,12,13
1,2,3,4,6,8,12,14
1,2,3,4,6,8,12,15
1,2,3,4,6,8,13,14
1,2,3,4,6,8,13,15
1,2,3,4,6,8,14,15
1,2,3,4,6,9,10,11
1,2,3,4,6,9,10,12
1,2,3,4,6,9,10,13
1,2,3,4,6,9,10,14
1,2,3,4,6,9,10,15
1,2,3,4,6,9,11,12
1,2,3,4,6,9,11,13
1,2,3,4,6,9,11,14
1,2,3,4,6,9,11,15
1,2,3,4,6,9,12,13
1,2,3,4,6,9,12,14
1,2,3,4,6,9,12,15
1,2,3,4,6,9,13,14
1,2,3,4,6,9,13,15
1,2,3,4,6,9,14,15
1,2,3,4,6,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,6,10,11,13
1,2,3,4,6,10,11,14
1,2,3,4,6,10,11,15
1,2,3,4,6,10,12,13
1,2,3,4,6,10,12,14
1,2,3,4,6,10,12,15
1,2,3,4,6,10,13,14
1,2,3,4,6,10,13,15
1,2,3,4,6,10,14,15
1,2,3,4,6,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,6,11,12,14
1,2,3,4,6,11,12,15
1,2,3,4,6,11,13,14
1,2,3,4,6,11,13,15
1,2,3,4,6,11,14,15
1,2,3,4,6,12,13,14
1,2,3,4,6,12,13,15
1,2,3,4,6,12,14,15
1,2,3,4,6,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,11
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,12
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,13
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,14
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,15
1,2,3,4,7,8,10,11
1,2,3,4,7,8,10,12
1,2,3,4,7,8,10,13
1,2,3,4,7,8,10,14
1,2,3,4,7,8,10,15
1,2,3,4,7,8,11,12
1,2,3,4,7,8,11,13
1,2,3,4,7,8,11,14
1,2,3,4,7,8,11,15
1,2,3,4,7,8,12,13
1,2,3,4,7,8,12,14
1,2,3,4,7,8,12,15
1,2,3,4,7,8,13,14
1,2,3,4,7,8,13,15
1,2,3,4,7,8,14,15
1,2,3,4,7,9,10,11
1,2,3,4,7,9,10,12
1,2,3,4,7,9,10,13
1,2,3,4,7,9,10,14
1,2,3,4,7,9,10,15
1,2,3,4,7,9,11,12
1,2,3,4,7,9,11,13
1,2,3,4,7,9,11,14
1,2,3,4,7,9,11,15
1,2,3,4,7,9,12,13
1,2,3,4,7,9,12,14
1,2,3,4,7,9,12,15
1,2,3,4,7,9,13,14
1,2,3,4,7,9,13,15
1,2,3,4,7,9,14,15
1,2,3,4,7,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,7,10,11,13
1,2,3,4,7,10,11,14
1,2,3,4,7,10,11,15
1,2,3,4,7,10,12,13
1,2,3,4,7,10,12,14
1,2,3,4,7,10,12,15
1,2,3,4,7,10,13,14
1,2,3,4,7,10,13,15
1,2,3,4,7,10,14,15
1,2,3,4,7,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,7,11,12,14
1,2,3,4,7,11,12,15
1,2,3,4,7,11,13,14
1,2,3,4,7,11,13,15
1,2,3,4,7,11,14,15
1,2,3,4,7,12,13,14
1,2,3,4,7,12,13,15
1,2,3,4,7,12,14,15
1,2,3,4,7,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,8,9,10,11
1,2,3,4,8,9,10,12
1,2,3,4,8,9,10,13
1,2,3,4,8,9,10,14
1,2,3,4,8,9,10,15
1,2,3,4,8,9,11,12
1,2,3,4,8,9,11,13
1,2,3,4,8,9,11,14
1,2,3,4,8,9,11,15
1,2,3,4,8,9,12,13
1,2,3,4,8,9,12,14
1,2,3,4,8,9,12,15
1,2,3,4,8,9,13,14
1,2,3,4,8,9,13,15
1,2,3,4,8,9,14,15
1,2,3,4,8,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,8,10,11,13
1,2,3,4,8,10,11,14
1,2,3,4,8,10,11,15
1,2,3,4,8,10,12,13
1,2,3,4,8,10,12,14
1,2,3,4,8,10,12,15
1,2,3,4,8,10,13,14
1,2,3,4,8,10,13,15
1,2,3,4,8,10,14,15
1,2,3,4,8,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,8,11,12,14
1,2,3,4,8,11,12,15
1,2,3,4,8,11,13,14
1,2,3,4,8,11,13,15
1,2,3,4,8,11,14,15
1,2,3,4,8,12,13,14
1,2,3,4,8,12,13,15
1,2,3,4,8,12,14,15
1,2,3,4,8,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,9,10,11,12
1,2,3,4,9,10,11,13
1,2,3,4,9,10,11,14
1,2,3,4,9,10,11,15
1,2,3,4,9,10,12,13
1,2,3,4,9,10,12,14
1,2,3,4,9,10,12,15
1,2,3,4,9,10,13,14
1,2,3,4,9,10,13,15
1,2,3,4,9,10,14,15
1,2,3,4,9,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,9,11,12,14
1,2,3,4,9,11,12,15
1,2,3,4,9,11,13,14
1,2,3,4,9,11,13,15
1,2,3,4,9,11,14,15
1,2,3,4,9,12,13,14
1,2,3,4,9,12,13,15
1,2,3,4,9,12,14,15
1,2,3,4,9,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,10,11,12,13
1,2,3,4,10,11,12,14
1,2,3,4,10,11,12,15
1,2,3,4,10,11,13,14
1,2,3,4,10,11,13,15
1,2,3,4,10,11,14,15
1,2,3,4,10,12,13,14
1,2,3,4,10,12,13,15
1,2,3,4,10,12,14,15
1,2,3,4,10,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,11,12,13,14
1,2,3,4,11,12,13,15
1,2,3,4,11,12,14,15
1,2,3,4,11,13,14,15
1,2,3,4,12,13,14,15
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,11
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,12
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,13
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,14
1,2,3,5,6,7,8,15
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,10
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,11
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,12
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,13
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,14
1,2,3,5,6,7,9,15
1,2,3,5,6,7,10,11
1,2,3,5,6,7,10,12
1,2,3,5,6,7,10,13
1,2,3,5,6,7,10,14
1,2,3,5,6,7,10,15
1,2,3,5,6,7,11,12
1,2,3,5,6,7,11,13
1,2,3,5,6,7,11,14
1,2,3,5,6,7,11,15
1,2,3,5,6,7,12,13
1,2,3,5,6,7,12,14
1,2,3,5,6,7,12,15
1,2,3,5,6,7,13,14
1,2,3,5,6,7,13,15
1,2,3,5,6,7,14,15
1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10
1,2,3,5,6,8,9,11
1,2,3,5,6,8,9,12
1,2,3,5,6,8,9,13
1,2,3,5,6,8,9,14
1,2,3,5,6,8,9,15
1,2,3,5,6,8,10,11
1,2,3,5,6,8,10,12
1,2,3,5,6,8,10,13
1,2,3,5,6,8,10,14
1,2,3,5,6,8,10,15
1,2,3,5,6,8,11,12
1,2,3,5,6,8,11,13
1,2,3,5,6,8,11,14
1,2,3,5,6,8,11,15
1,2,3,5,6,8,12,13
1,2,3,5,6,8,12,14
1,2,3,5,6,8,12,15
1,2,3,5,6,8,13,14
1,2,3,5,6,8,13,15
1,2,3,5,6,8,14,15
1,2,3,5,6,9,10,11
1,2,3,5,6,9,10,12
1,2,3,5,6,9,10,13
1,2,3,5,6,9,10,14
1,2,3,5,6,9,10,15
1,2,3,5,6,9,11,12
1,2,3,5,6,9,11,13
...
```

run the code yourself to get the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're being asked to LIST them? 
 This is the combinations function on your calculator and you will realise that you are expecting to receive a large number of options, in fact $C(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ in this case we have $C(16,8)=\frac{16!}{(16-8)!8!}=12870$